# Comma Separator in DecimalPipe

Tags: angular, typescript, decimal-point

Is it possible to format the number `0,00` with `DecimalPipe` without specifying Locale?

I have a requirement where I've to format the number `0,00` or `0.00` regardless of the locale.

The below code throwing error saying it is not a valid number

```
this.decimalPipe.formatNumber('0,00', '.2-2')
```

I don't prefer doing this way to fix it

```
let num = '0,00';

num = num.replace(',','.')

this.decimalPipe.formatNumber(num, '.2-2')
```

Comment: Why not *pass a locale* to the actual decimal pipe? Hard code the locale based on what you want to display. Again, *not* stating you set the `LOCALE_ID`, just that you pass a string value to the pipe call in the template or in the call to `formatNumber`.

Comment: Why not extend the DecimalPipe and simply replacing it there? Then you'd have the logic in one place.

Comment: If you don't specify the locale, how would you differentiate between cases where the period is used as a decimal separator and cases where it is used as thousands separator?

Comment: Numbers in javascript do not retain the floating-point count. so you would have to keep them as strings and calculate against them as floats `"0,00".replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ".$1")` this would only replace the last comma with dot.

Comment: @Igor, because even in any other locale there should be formatted with `comma` as it based on the configuration either `,` or `.` as a separator for decimal and so would like to go the other way if any

Comment: @ConnorsFan, that is based on the user settings

Comment: @seBaka28, Please post if you've got any example

Comment: @SouravDutta, I don't wish to go for string replacement

Comment: You misunderstand me. Pass the locale for how you want to display the decimal, *not* the locale associated with the user context. Example: If you wanted to use comma , to indicate the fractional component of the number then pass in a Dutch locale even if the user context is currently English.

Comment: Let me clarify you, there are a lot of locales which uses `,` as decimal separator. My requirement is purely based on the user configuration which means the user can belong `en-US` locale but still needed `,` as separator and so, I cannot use `this.formatNumber('0,00', 'fr')` for e.g.

Comment: `I cannot use this.formatNumber('0,00', 'fr')` ← Why not? How does that not satisfy the requirement? Pick a locale for period and one for comma and then use the appropriate when depending on what you want to display. It does not matter what the user has selected as their locale, these are not dependent on each other at all.

Comment: I can go with that if that is the proper way! I thought the user doesn't belong to 'fr' then why should I explicitly set the locale 'fr' instead of `en-US`

Comment: @Igor `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "fr".' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'. ` This means I want to include 'fr' in `AppModule` which creates additional overhead to the application

Comment: The addition of a locale creates minimal overhead. You can look at the locale file yourself  in `/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/fr.js`. It's 12kb in size but it will be minified when included so that will compress down to about 2kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request an implementation of a comma separated pipe, instead of going for string replacement I used the suggestion by @Igor and simply instantiate with a locale, that does use a comma as a decimal separator:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'commaDecimal'
})
export class CommaSeparaterDecimalPipe extends DecimalPipe {

  // Use a locale which has a comma separator, don't forget to register it
  transform(value: any, digitsInfo?: string, locale = 'fr'): string | null {
    return super.transform(value, digitsInfo, locale);
  }

}
```

In my opinion it is a lot cleaner, if you have a specific pipe for your use case so you have a single reference point, in case there need to be different changes in the future. If you'd rather go with string replacement after all, simply assign the return value from the super call, do the string manipulation and return the value. E.g.

```
let transformed = super.transform(value, digitsInfo, locale);
return `:) ${transformed}`; // using back ticks here
```

to render each number with a prefixed smiley.

**Edit**:
Seeing as in the question you only seem to use the `formatNumber()` method, a pipe might not be the best solution for you seeing as the strong point of pipes is them being usable in HTML. So if you only ever call `formatNumber`, you can also simply export your own function:

```
import {formatNumber} from '@angular/common';

export function formatCommaDecimalNumber(value: number, locale = 'en-US', digitsInfo = '.2-2'): string { 
    // No need to instantiate Pipes at least since Angular 8
    let formatted = formatNumber(value, locale, digitsInfo);

    // Handle string replacement
    ...
    return formatted;
}
```

If you also need this functionality in HTML, simply create the custom pipe anyway, but call your custom `formatCommaDecimalNumber` function there instead of duplicating the logic.

Comment: `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "fr".' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'. ` This means I want to include 'fr' in `AppModule` which creates additional overhead to the application

Comment: Yes, that is why I added the comment about registering the locale. If you do not want that additional overhead of having a different locale, I would suggest going with a string replacement solution in the custom pipe.

Comment: `{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' }` - Will it change the entire application to the french locale with this or only when needed. Sorry not clear on this?

Comment: If you do this, then you override the default value of `en-US` that every Angular application has. What you need to do is to just register the locale, so it is available. 
To do so you add `registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR');` to your AppModule. The imports are from `@angular/common`. I'd advise you to also check out the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes